# Having a same temp table name with 2 different IF statements

Tags: sql, sql-server

**I have resolved this problem because I have overlooked something that is already part of my code and this situation is not needed.**

In SQL Server 2008, I have two IF statements

```
If value = ''
begin 
select * into #temptable from table 1
end
Else If value <> ''
begin 
select * into #temptable from table 2
end
```

but when I try to execute it gives me because of the second

## temptable:

```
There is already an object named '#temptable' in the database.
```

I don't want to use another temp table name as I would have to change the after code a lot. Is there a way to bypass this?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend making some changes so that your code is a little more maintainable.  One problem  with the way you have it set up here is with the `SELECT *` syntax you're using.  If you later decide to make a change to the schema of table1 or table2, you could have non-obvious consequences. In production code, it's better to spell these things out so that it's clear exactly which columns you're using and where.

Also, are you really using all of the columns from table 1 and table 2 in the code that follows?  You might be taking a performance hit loading more data than you need.  I'd go through the code that uses #temptable and figure out which columns it's actually using.  Then start by creating your temp table:

```
CREATE TABLE #temptable(col1 int, col2 int, col3 int, col4 int)
```

Include all of the possible columns that could be used, even if some of them might be null in certain cases.  Presumably, the code that follows already understands that.  Then you can set up your IF statements:

```
IF value = ''
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO #temptable(col1, col2, col3)
    SELECT x,y,z
    FROM table1
END

ELSE
    INSERT INTO #temptable(col1, col4)
    SELECT alpha,beta
    FROM table2
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Your SELECT statement, as written, is creating the temp table and INSERTING into it all in one statement.  Create the temp table separately with a CREATE TABLE statement, then INSERT INTO in your two IF statements.

Comment: The table in question is dynamically created with different amount of columns each time it is executed. How can I create such table?

Comment: Maybe a little more context would help -- what are you trying to accomplish with this table that sometimes looks like "table 1" and sometimes looks like "table 2"?

Answer (score 0):

Using `SELECT INTO` creates the table on the fly, as you know.  Even if your query only referenced `#temptable` once, if you were to run it more than once (without dropping the table after the first run), you would get the same error (although if it were inside a stored procedure, it would probably only exist in the scope of the stored procedure).

However, you can't even compile this query.  Using the Parse command (`Ctrl+F5`) on the following query, for example, fails even though the same table is used as the source table.

```
select * into #temptable from SourceTable
select * into #temptable from SourceTable
```

If the structure of tables 1 and 2 were the same, you could do something like the following.

```
select * into #temptable from
    (select * from Table1 where @value = ''
    union
    select * from Table2 where @value <> '') as T
```

If, however, the tables have different structures, then I'm not sure what you can do, other than what [agt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1416727/agt) and [D. Lambert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/65131/d-lambert) recommended.